# Connect AppleID on New MacBook, but worried it will automatically sync everything

Tags: macos, mac, ios, apple-id

Is there a way to sign in to my apple ID on my new macbook (via AppStore), but stop it from syncing things automatically? I don't want to have all my old Notes, Reminders, Calendar Events pollute my new macbook

Comment: Have you looked in `System Preferences > Internet Accounts > iCloud`? You can selectively sync all that you mention and then some. AppStore login only effects the AppStore itself and those are a manual download unless you have Automatic Updates selected in App Store preferences.

Comment: I agree w/ Steve's comment - you CAN turn off most sync items.  However, I think you can only do that AFTER you login with your ID, so do it quickly.  If you wait, you can still turn it off, and some things (like Contacts) ask if you want to keep a copy or not, but it's possible you'll still have some remnants.  The purpose of iCloud *is* to sync all this stuff, though, so if you don't want them, delete them using your old Mac first, if you still have it, then you can really control what will show up on the new Mac.  You might want those things turned on later on the new 'book, they're useful!

Comment: If you want zero cross-pollination, set up a new Apple ID - though this will mean they are forever separate.